# Going back to previous activity onBackPressed

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I have a cartActivity and when I click the proceed button it goes to PaymentActivity. Now, If I click baack button from the paymentActivity I want to go back to the CartActivity.

CartActivity

```
class CartActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
lateinit var txtOrderingFrom: TextView
lateinit var btnPlaceOrder: Button
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
lateinit var menuAdapter: CartAdapter
lateinit var restaurantId: String
lateinit var restaurantName: String
lateinit var selectedItemsId: ArrayList<String>
lateinit var linearLayout: LinearLayout
lateinit var cartProgressLayout: RelativeLayout

var totalAmount = 0
var cartListItems = arrayListOf<CartItems>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart)

    btnPlaceOrder = findViewById(R.id.btnPlaceOrder)
    txtOrderingFrom = findViewById(R.id.txtOrderingFrom)
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout)
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar)
    cartProgressLayout = findViewById(R.id.cartProgressLayout)

    restaurantId = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantId").toString()
    restaurantName = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantName").toString()
    selectedItemsId = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("selectedItemsId") as ArrayList<String>
    txtOrderingFrom.text = restaurantName

    setToolBar()
    fetchData()

    btnPlaceOrder.setOnClickListener {



        val sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.shared_preferences),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )

        if (ConnectionManager().checkConnectivity(this)) {

            cartProgressLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            try {
                val foodArray = JSONArray()

                for (foodItem in selectedItemsId) {
                    val singleItemObject = JSONObject()
                    singleItemObject.put("food_item_id", foodItem)
                    foodArray.put(singleItemObject)
                }

                val sendOrder = JSONObject()
                sendOrder.put("user_id", sharedPreferences.getString("user_id", "0"))
                sendOrder.put("restaurant_id", restaurantId)
                sendOrder.put("total_cost", totalAmount)
                sendOrder.put("food", foodArray)

                val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
                val url = "http://13.235.250.119/v2/place_order/fetch_result"

                val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
                    Method.POST,
                    url,
                    sendOrder,
                    Response.Listener {

                        val response = it.getJSONObject("data")
                        val success = response.getBoolean("success")
                        val LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY = 1
                        if (success) {
                            val intent = Intent(this, PaymentActivity::class.java)
                            intent.putExtra("total_amount",totalAmount)
                            startActivityForResult(intent,LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY)
                            finishAffinity()

                        } else {
                            val responseMessageServer =
                                response.getString("errorMessage")
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                responseMessageServer.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()

                        }
                        cartProgressLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    },
                    Response.ErrorListener {

                        Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "Some Error occurred!!!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }) {
                    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                        headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
                        headers["token"] = "9bf534118365f1"
                        return headers
                    }
                }
                queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)

            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Some unexpected error occurred!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }

        } else {

            val alterDialog = androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            alterDialog.setTitle("No Internet")
            alterDialog.setMessage("Check Internet Connection!")
            alterDialog.setPositiveButton("Open Settings") { _, _ ->
                val settingsIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)
                startActivity(settingsIntent)
            }
            alterDialog.setNegativeButton("Exit") { _, _ ->
                finishAffinity()
            }
            alterDialog.setCancelable(false)
            alterDialog.create()
            alterDialog.show()
        }
    }

    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCart)

}

fun fetchData() {

    if (ConnectionManager().checkConnectivity(this)) {

        cartProgressLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        try {
            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
            val url = "http://13.235.250.119/v2/restaurants/fetch_result/$restaurantId"

            val jsonObjectRequest = @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            object : JsonObjectRequest(
                Method.GET,
                url,
                null,
                Response.Listener {

                    val response = it.getJSONObject("data")
                    val success = response.getBoolean("success")
                    if (success) {

                        val data = response.getJSONArray("data")
                        cartListItems.clear()
                        totalAmount = 0

                        for (i in 0 until data.length()) {
                            val cartItem = data.getJSONObject(i)
                            if (selectedItemsId.contains(cartItem.getString("id"))) {
                                val menuObject = CartItems(
                                    cartItem.getString("id"),
                                    cartItem.getString("name"),
                                    cartItem.getString("cost_for_one"),
                                    cartItem.getString("restaurant_id")
                                )

                                totalAmount += cartItem.getString("cost_for_one").toString()
                                    .toInt()
                                cartListItems.add(menuObject)


                            }
                            menuAdapter = CartAdapter(this, cartListItems)
                            recyclerView.adapter = menuAdapter
                            recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
                        }

                        btnPlaceOrder.text = "Place Order(Total: Rs. $totalAmount)"

                    }
                    cartProgressLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                },
                Response.ErrorListener {

                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Some Error occurred!!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()

                    cartProgressLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }) {
                override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                    headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
                    headers["token"] = "26c5144c5b9c13"
                    return headers
                }
            }

            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)

        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Some Unexpected error occurred!!!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

    } else {

        val alterDialog = androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        alterDialog.setTitle("No Internet")
        alterDialog.setMessage("Check Internet Connection!")
        alterDialog.setPositiveButton("Open Settings") { _, _ ->
            val settingsIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(settingsIntent)
        }
        alterDialog.setNegativeButton("Exit") { _, _ ->
            finishAffinity()
        }
        alterDialog.setCancelable(false)
        alterDialog.create()
        alterDialog.show()
    }
}

fun setToolBar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.title = "My Cart"
    supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back_arrow)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

}

PaymentActivity

```
 class PaymentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var amountEt: TextView? = null
    var nameEt: TextView? = null
    var upiIdEt: TextView? = null
    var send: Button? = null
    val UPI_PAYMENT = 0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment)
        initializeViews()
        send?.setOnClickListener {
            payUsingUpi("1", "sruthikrithika0@okhdfcbank", "Sruthi")
            }

    }

    fun initializeViews() {
        send = findViewById(R.id.send)
        amountEt = findViewById(R.id.amount_et)
        nameEt = findViewById(R.id.upi_name)
        upiIdEt = findViewById(R.id.upi_id)
    }

    fun payUsingUpi(amount: String?, upiId: String?, name: String?) {
        val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay").buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("pa", upiId)
            .appendQueryParameter("pn", name)
            .appendQueryParameter("am", amount)
            .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
            .build()
        val upiPayIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        upiPayIntent.data = uri

        // will always show a dialog to user to choose an app
        val chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with")

        // check if intent resolves
        if (null != chooser.resolveActivity(packageManager)) {
            startActivityForResult(chooser, UPI_PAYMENT)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@PaymentActivity,
                "No UPI app found, please install one to continue",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            UPI_PAYMENT -> if (RESULT_OK == resultCode || resultCode == 11) {
                if (data != null) {
                    val trxt = data.getStringExtra("response")
                    Log.d("UPI", "onActivityResult: $trxt")
                    val dataList: ArrayList<String?> = ArrayList()
                    dataList.add(trxt)
                    upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList)
                } else {
                    Log.d("UPI", "onActivityResult: " + "Return data is null")
                    val dataList: ArrayList<String?> = ArrayList()
                    dataList.add("nothing")
                    upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList)
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(
                    "UPI",
                    "onActivityResult: " + "Return data is null"
                ) //when user simply back without payment
                val dataList: ArrayList<String?> = ArrayList()
                dataList.add("nothing")
                upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun upiPaymentDataOperation(data: ArrayList<String?>) {
        if (isConnectionAvailable(this@PaymentActivity)) {
            var str = data[0]
            Log.d("UPIPAY", "upiPaymentDataOperation: $str")
            var paymentCancel = ""
            if (str == null) str = "discard"
            var status = ""
            var approvalRefNo = ""
            val response = str.split("&").toTypedArray()
            for (i in response.indices) {
                val equalStr = response[i].split("=").toTypedArray()
                if (equalStr.size >= 2) {
                    if (equalStr[0].toLowerCase() == "Status".toLowerCase()) {
                        status = equalStr[1].toLowerCase()
                    } else if (equalStr[0].toLowerCase() == "ApprovalRefNo".toLowerCase() || equalStr[0].toLowerCase() == "txnRef".toLowerCase()) {
                        approvalRefNo = equalStr[1]
                    }
                } else {
                    paymentCancel = "Payment cancelled by user."
                }
            }
            if (status == "success") {
                //Code to handle successful transaction here.
                Toast.makeText(this@PaymentActivity, "Transaction successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                Log.d("UPI", "responseStr: $approvalRefNo")
            } else if ("Payment cancelled by user." == paymentCancel) {
                Toast.makeText(this@PaymentActivity, "Payment cancelled by user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@PaymentActivity,
                    "Transaction failed.Please try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@PaymentActivity,
                "Internet connection is not available. Please check and try again",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun isConnectionAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
            val connectivityManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            if (connectivityManager != null) {
                val netInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
                if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected
                    && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
                    && netInfo.isAvailable
                ) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

Now, when I click back button from PaymentActivity the app crashes because the same state in the cartActivity is not present.How to resolve this ??

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.foodly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Foodly">
        <activity android:name=".activity.OrderPlacedActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.CartActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.OrderHistoryActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.RestaurantMenuActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.RegisterActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PaymentActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It would help if you showed your stack trace and indicated which line it corresponds with so we don't have to carefully read through all that code to spot the error...

Comment: If u see the PaymentActivity, I have implemented the onBackPressed.But if I press back it isn't going back because the cart items is not saved

Comment: Are you going to make me beg for the stack trace? ;)

Comment: You've taken the time to respond to multiple answers - if you'd taken that time to post the stacktrace of your crash this would probably be resolved already.

Comment: I actually don't know how to do it. I'm new to android. I am sorry @dominicoder

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces

Comment: If I do that, the entire PaymentActivivty code is shown in run.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `startActivity()` in your `OnBackPressed()` callback ? You don't have to, it's automatic. If you need to retrieve parameters in the `CartActivity`, you have to launch the `PaymentActivity` with `startActivityForResult()`

Comment: It isn't actually going back to the previous activity. The app is closing entirely.

Comment: Because of `finishAffinity()`certainly. Don't call the `finish()`method on an Activity you want to go back to

Comment: No, even after removin finishAffinity() the app loses with an error mesage, that cart Activity is null.The state isn't saved.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the

> finishAffinity()

`finishAffinity()` is used to remove a number of Activitys belonging to a specific application from the current task (which may contain Activitys belonging to multiple applications).

You shouldn't be doing any finish on starting payment activity. you should be using `finishAffinity()` after payment success so the last activities should not come on back press.

For more info - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finishAffinity()

Comment: No, even after removin finishAffinity() the app loses with an error mesage, that cart Activity is null.The state isn't saved

Comment: is this happening on back press on payment activity?

Comment: yes, when I press back button in payment activity the app is closing. I know why this is happening but dont know how to solve it. From cart activtity when I move to next activity the list in cart activity goes away

Comment: pls, remove onBackPressed() method from payment activity after removing finish and finishAffinity in cart activity.

Comment: Still the same happens

Comment: have you removed finishAffinity() method from cart activity? onbackpress it should be coming to cart activity. pls share your manifest code for payment and cart activity also

Comment: I have uploaded everything here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234950/discussion-between-yazhini-and-happy-singh).